# How do I create Extension Methods for string type in Asp.net MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, extension-methods

Hi I'm trying to reach this goal but as far as I am, I've got nothing. 
I wish to add some static method to string type, which would return new changed string. I've got: using System;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
namespace TestProject.Models
{
    public static class Extension
    {
        public static string md5(this string input)
        {

            MD5 HashAlgorithm = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            Byte[] InputsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input3);
            Byte[] HashedInput = HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(InputsBytes);
            return BitConverter.ToString(HashedInput);
        }
    }
}
```

honestly I just don't know where should it be. I put it in my models catalog but I'm pretty sure it's wrong. Where should it be? And what then? I'd like to use it in this way:

```
string hashedString = String.md5(input);
```

Comment: input3 should be input right?

Comment: yes, sry for that it's cause I simplified my code here in textBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this : `string hashedString = input.md5();`

Extension methods are compiler trick the actual call is just a normal static method call.

The compiler  just turns the code into:

`string hashedString = TestProject.Models.Extentions.md5(input)`

Comment: it helps! ;) but why is that if I daclare it as a static method? is it feature of extensions?

Comment: The method is static because you don't need an object of the Extension class to use it.